# Correlation of yield data within a buffer zone

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, buffer, correlation

[image]

Working with QGIS 2.12.1-Lyon, I am trying to compare one point (single shapefile) with multiple others that fall within a buffer zone of 10m i.e. comparing one shapefile with another.

The end product I am trying to calculate is a correlation between the one point and; the nearest point, the average within a 10m radius and the average within a 5 meter row.

The data I am working with is yield data from a wheat field. The correlation is with 1 biomass sample and multiple yield data points.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here, just a set of statements.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the "select by position" tool from the QGIS vector tools (vector--> research tools--> select by position)?

Simply select the point layer as the source layer and the buffer layer as the overlaying layer.

You can then save the selection if needed and perform further analysis on the selection.

Hope this helps